# ログイン画面にアクセスした際に複数のpythonファイルを同時に実行する方法

Tags: python, php, python3, opencv

下記のログインページにアクセスした際に、別に自作しているmultiface_ac.pyとmyface_ac.pyを同時に実行させるようなコードを書きたいのですが、そのような方法はあるのでしょうか。わかる方いれば何卒宜しくお願い致します

```
<h1>ログインページ</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label>
        学籍番号：
        <input type="text" name="id" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        パスワード：
        <input type="password" name="pass" required>
    </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="ログイン">
</form>
```